# SQL Server Azure "Login failed for User"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, sqlconnection

I am using the following code to perform SQL commands to my azure DB. The I do two calls inside my ASP.NET MVC action method. One to delete from Table A, and the second call to delete from Table B.

```
  using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                command.CommandText = statement;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

For whatever reason when I make the second call to this code (I have it in a Helper service class, it bombs with the following Azure error.

```
Additional information: Login failed for user 'MyUser'.
```

Is there something I'm not doing correctly but not perhaps closing a connection or something that Azure is having issues with this?

Comment: What does your connection string look like (remember to blank out personal data)? I bet you are using Windows Authentication and your Sql server does not have a login for the user that the webserver is running as.

Comment: And what are the commands you are executing?

Comment: Commands: delete from table1, delete from table2

Comment: I just noticed something.. I am pulling the connection string from the Entity Framework Entities class. "MyEntity.Database.Connection.ConnectionString" the second time I call into it the password for the connection string is missing.. why is this?

Comment: Do you have Persist Security Info=True?

Comment: If you can't fix, alternatively you can execute both delete queries in a single command separated by semicolon like this. delete from table1; delete from table2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need allow your IP Address to access azure database. click in configure and add your IP.

Comment: How does one allow firewall access for an App Service? I only get this error in production (no matter what my connection information is in my web config) but the app service doesn't have an IP.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed add to the connection string

```
Persist Security Info=False;
```

Answer (score 0):

when you publish your project into azure from visual studio, there is a 'settings' tab on the left.

go to the settings. it will show you the connection string that you're using in the web.config.

what worked for me is I unchecked the check box that says 'Use this connection string at runtime (update destination web.config)' and everything went well for me.