# How to solve the connection when the login failed during C# programming in database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I did some coding on connecting data using Azure database on Windows Form and when I tried to retrieve the data, I received the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll.

Also in addition, I received a `Login failed for user ''.` When I tried to retrieve the data and located at `myConnection.Open();`

```
private void btnRetrieve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create a connection calling the App.config
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NYPConnection"].ConnectionString;
    //The query to use
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Users";
    SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(conn);
    //Create a Data Adapter
    SqlDataAdapter dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, myconnection);
    //Create the dataset
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    //Open the connection
    ******myconnection.Open();******

    //Fill the Data Adapter
    dadapter.Fill(ds, "Users");
    myconnection.Close();
    //Bind the datagridview with the data set
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
    dataGridView1.DataMember = "Users";
}
```

Comment: It appears that the database user credentials in the connection string is not correct.

Comment: Perhaps the answer to this question will solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510804/sql-server-azure-login-failed-for-user

Answer (score 1):

Print out the value of `conn`, using the following code:

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NYPConnection"].ConnectionString;
Debug.WriteLine("conn= " + conn);
```

Have a look in the output window and you will probably find that  `conn` is set to an empty string or maybe does not have the user name specified.